# Websocket Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I am trying to use websocket Java with spring 4. I have created a server handler.
Here is my code

```js
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.springframework.web.socket.CloseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.TextWebSocketHandler;

public class ServerHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler{
 
 private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
 
 @Override
 public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  logger.info("Connection clodes with websocket server: session id " + session.getId());
 }
 
 @Override
 public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  logger.info("Connected user with websocket server: session id " + session.getId());
 }
 
 @Override
 public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession session, WebSocketMessage<?> message) throws Exception {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  super.handleMessage(session, message);
 }
 
 @Override
 public void handleTransportError(WebSocketSession session, Throwable exception) throws Exception {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.handleTransportError(session, exception);
 }
}
```

Next i have created a websocket configurer. Here is the code

```js
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebsocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer{

 
 @Override
 public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addHandler(myHandler(), "/websocket").withSockJS();
  
 }
 
 @Bean
    public ServerHandler myHandler() {
        return new ServerHandler();
    }
 
}
```

In my client (JavaScript), i tried to connect to the server

```js
var sock = new SockJS('http://localhost:9999/websocket');
```

When i tried to execute the client, i got a 404 error
Where is the problem?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add @Controller annotation to WebsocketConfig class so it can handle the request coming from client.

```
@EnableWebSocket
@Controller
public class WebsocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer{
```

And set setAllowedOrigins() to avoid error in connecting with different domain.

```
registry.addHandler(myHandler(), "/websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
```

Comment: After update, i got another error:           XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9999/websocket/info?t=1474989961280. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: I have removed @Configuration annotation in WebsocketConfig

Comment: Are you setting setAllowedOrigins("*") as I given in my answer above?

Comment: Yes i have set allowOrigin

Comment: Yes i have set allowOrigin.

Comment: Try setting CORS for entire application. More info here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html#_javaconfig . I believe that during initialization of websocket connection, a regular HTTP request is made that causes this error to appear.